# Ошибка в cstdio (нет fgetpos и fsetpos)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, terminal, vim

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь установить YouCompleteMe для подсказок в Vim.

Запускаю install.sh или install.py и всё идёт. Но потом выводит ошибки, мол, в cstdio нет мемберов fgetpos и fsetpos. 
Но если их использовать в своих программах, то эти функции есть.
Пользуюсь андроид терминалом Termux.

Лог ошибки:

> In file included from /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:440:
>   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdio:137:9: error:
>         no member named 'fgetpos' in the global
>         namespace
>   using ::fgetpos;
>         ~~^
>   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdio:139:9: error:
>         no member named 'fsetpos' in the global
>         namespace
>   using ::fsetpos;
>         ~~^

Comment: Прототипы этих функций описаны в заголовке "#include <stdio.h>". Почему он у Вас не подключается - это уж Вам разбираться надо.

Comment: @Sergey это похоже на [ошибку в android-ndk](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/480). Оно исправлена, но ещё не выпущена.